# Spinner if else statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement, spinner

I would like to do if else statement for Spinner.
I declare "june","july","august","sept","oct","nov","dec"

When I click on "August" it will give me MainActivity.java
else it will give me August.java.
Right now, 
My spinner is auto select,
meaning, when I load the page, it will auto select "june" for me.
is there a way, for me to disable to auto select?

This is my code

```
String [] months = {
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "Septemeber",
                "November",
                "December",
```

part of my date.java

```
//SpinnerView
            s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, months);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have seleted item :" + months[index] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0) {}
            });


    if ( s1.equals("August")) {

        startActivity(new Intent(date.this,MainActivity.class));
    }
    else{
        startActivity(new Intent(date.this,august
                .class));

    }
```

Comment: why don't you change  String [] months = {
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "Septemeber",
                "November",
                "December"} as String [] months = {"Select"
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "Septemeber",
                "November",
                "December"};   ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Add array like  "Select Month","june","july","august","sept","oct","nov","dec"

and check in

```
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                if(index>0)
                {
                             String Month = MonthArray[index];
                    if ( Month.equalIgnoreCase("August")) {

                        startActivity(new Intent(date.this,MainActivity.class));
                    }
                    else{
                        startActivity(new Intent(date.this,august
                                .class));

                    }
                }
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0) {}
        });
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Try edited Code. Get String from array of Months and then check if its equal to "August" or not??

Comment: can take a look at this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266824/spinner-with-list-view

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class date extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{



    ArrayList<String> months;

    Spinner spinner;

    ArrayAdapter<String> month_adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        months = new ArrayList<String>();

        months.add("Select");
        months.add("June");
        months.add("July");
        months.add("August");
        months.add("Septemeber");
        months.add("November");
        months.add("December");

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); 
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        month_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, months);
        month_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(month_adapter);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(!(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Select")))
        {

            if ( spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("August")) {

                startActivity(new Intent(date.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
            else{
                startActivity(new Intent(date.this,august
                            .class));

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: can take a look at this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266824/spinner-with-list-view

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `Spinner`'s last selected item position either in your DB or in `SharedPreference`. When your application loads, check whether have you item position in your DB or in `SharedPreference`, and then select the item in the `Spinner` based on this position.